# C# styling parameters Visual Studio configuration

Tags: visual-studio

I usually write parameters like:

```
private void function name( int value )
{
    function.Something( Convert.ToInt( value ) );
}
```

But Visual Studio changes it so in the function declaration it allows the spaces but inside the function it automatically removes the spaces, I wonder how I can change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Visual Studio's menu => **Tools** => **Options** => **Text editor** => **C#** => **Formatting** => **Spacing** and then select the desired options. The two ticked items in the image below should be suitable.

[image: Example of options needed]